# Cannot parse German day of week abbreviation with SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, datetime

I want to parse German day of week like `Mo, Di, Mi, Do, Fr, Sa, So`. I'm using `SimpleDateFormat` class which allows us to choose locale. My parsing method looks like this:

```java
private static int parseDayOfWeek(String day) {
    SimpleDateFormat dayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE", Locale.GERMANY);
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = dayFormat.parse(day);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(date);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    return calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
}
```

Everytime when I try to parse this abbreviation for day of week I become `ParseException`:

```java
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mo"
    at java.base/java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:395)
```

The thing is that in another class I'm using DayOfWeek enum to create the same abbreviation for German day of week and it's making correct abbreviation `Mo, Di, Mi, Do, Fr, Sa, So`:

```java
DayOfWeek in = DayOfWeek.of(fromInt);
string.append(in.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT_STANDALONE, Locale.GERMANY));
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What version of java are you using?  I can duplicate this error in ideone (java 12), but it works fine in eclipse on my PC (java 8).

Comment: @azurefrog I'm using Java 11.

Answer (score 1):

Try printing the result for formatting dates using that `SimpleDateFormat` to see what it expects.

```
SimpleDateFormat dayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE", Locale.GERMANY);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    System.out.println(dayFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
}
```

*Output (using Java 9.0.4, 10.0.2, 11.0.2, 12.0.1, 13.0.2)*

```
Mo.
Di.
Mi.
Do.
Fr.
Sa.
So.
```

*Output (using Java 1.7.0_75, 1.8.0_181)*

```
Mo
Di
Mi
Do
Fr
Sa
So
```

As you can see, Java 9+ expects the 2-letter day-of-week name to be followed by a `.` period.

Comment: The thing is that now after parse `Mo.` I become integer of `2` instead of `1`. I know that in Germany the first day of week is Monday, not Sunday. Can I define during parsing which day of week should be first?

Comment: @Dawid `Calendar.MONDAY` is the value `2`, so it's supposed to return `2` for a Monday. The javadoc of [`Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_WEEK) says: *Field number for `get` and `set` indicating the day of the week. This field takes values `SUNDAY`, `MONDAY`, `TUESDAY`, `WEDNESDAY`, `THURSDAY`, `FRIDAY`, and `SATURDAY`.* --- It does not define any meaning for the numerical value, only that the value is one of the 7 constants. The javadoc doesn't even show what the numerical values are.